# Where and when are empty strings detected and appended to the list returned by re.split(r'(\W*)', '...words...')?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Code:

```py
import re

re_split_list = re.split(r'(\W*)', '...words...')
print(re_split_list, type(re_split_list), len(re_split_list))
```

Actual Output:

```
['', '...', '', '', 'w', '', 'o', '', 'r', '', 'd', '', 's', '...', '', '', ''] <class 'list'> 17
```

Based on the resource (https://regex101.com/r/m857F0/1 [1]) provided by @jonrsharpe, I expected the following output.

Expected Output:

```
['', '...', '', 'w', '', 'o', '', 'r', '', 'd', '', 's', '...', ''] <class 'list> 14
```

So my updated question is, what is the functionality that causes the empty strings at indices 3 (element 4), 15, and 16 to be added to the list of substrings returned by python re.split? Why are there two empty strings between '...' and 'w' instead of one (as seen in the regex emulator, [https://regex101.com/r/m857F0/1][1]). And why are there two empty strings between the second ellipsis, '...', and the empty string matched at the end of the input string (also seen in the regex emulator)? What are the rules being applied to from method call to output?

Links:
[1]: https://regex101.com/r/m857F0/1

Other references:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#functions

Comment: It looks like you wanted `\W+`, _one_ or more non-word characters. _Zero_ or more includes empty strings: https://regex101.com/r/m857F0/1

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe! Your resource was helpful, however I'm having trouble matching where the empty strings at indices 3 (element 4), 15, and 16 originate. Would you happen to know why there are two empty strings between '...' and 'w' instead of one, and why there are 2 empty strings between the second ellipsis, '...', and the empty string matched at the end of the input string? I would love to know how this functionality works in case it's needed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` call matches the given regex at the following positions of your input string "...words...":

- index 0, match 3 characters: "..."
- index 3, match 0 characters: ""
- index 4, match 0 characters: ""
- index 5, match 0 characters: ""
- index 6, match 0 characters: ""
- index 7, match 0 characters: ""
- index 8, match 3 characters: "..."
- index 11, match 0 characters: ""

... 8 matches in total.

These are the same 8 matches you'd get with `findall` with the same arguments:

```
re.findall(r'\.*', '...words...') == ['...', '', '', '', '', '', '...', '']
```

Now with the `split` version these matches are captured with a capture group, and so they appear in the result list **at odd indices**. The parts that occur *between* the matched strings will end up at the *even* indices in the result:

As we had 8 matches for the odd indices, then in total we will have 8*2+1 = 17 elements in the result list. This will sometimes include empty strings that originate from the *same* location in the input string, but when this happens they are at alternating sides of an *empty* delimiter (also at that position).